# Google SDK / Dialogflow Deployment Error

Tags: deployment, terminal, sdk, gcloud, dialogflow-es

I've been following a tutorial on creating a chatbot with Dialogflow and I've reached the section to do the fulfillment. The Google Cloud SDK got installed but when it comes time to deploy the function I keep getting this error.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation

```
Jasons-MBP-3:~ jason$ sudo gcloud beta functions deploy Goddard --stage-bucket goddard.appspot.com --trigger-http
-2 ['./.git', './.gitignore']
-1 [False, False]
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/RunningChromeVersion'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

I tried sudo and updating the gcloud components but still the same thing. I went to the folder it says doesnt exist and I see the file there but it's an alias. When I click the alias Finder says it can't be opened because th original can't be found. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So a friend of mine told me that for this section it had to be running in the same directory where the index.js file is. In case anyone else gets stuck!